# How to access Literal conrol from Visual Web Part code file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part

I have added a literal control in my visual web part VisualWebPart1.ascx file as follows:

```
<asp:Literal id="slider"></asp:Literal>
```

I am trying to access it in VisualWebPart1.ascx.cs file as follows but it is not working:

```
protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      slider.Text = "Testing";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding `runat="server"` attribute in literal. Silly mistake!

Comment: lol yes it is ;), without the runat=server it wouldnt be available within the .cs as thats run at the server :)